# Scala Immutable Map returns different values for same key

Tags: scala, dictionary, reference, immutability

I have an application with consecutive look-ups in a scala.collection.immutable.Map, with the same key, which result in two different references being returned. Something like the below:

```
val v1 = m(key)
val v2 = m(key)
require(v1 eq v2) // fails!
```

I have not been able to reproduce this behavior in a small example, and I am wondering if there is any situation in which this could be reasonable/expected. The application is single threaded and I have isolated the issue by having the look-ups happen right after one another.

Comment: Do you have concurrency? Do you have side-effecting `hashcode` or `equals` methods?

Comment: The application is sequential (no concurrency). The `hashcode` is an `Int` `val` (unique to each object) and the `equals` compares the `hashcode` values.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are testing for reference equality. In which case v1 and v2 are different objects. Reference equality is the default for classes unless you create a case class.

Comment: But v1 and v2 should be the same object. If he used `get` then it would be a different story (different `Option` instances)

Comment: Luigi - I also expect the values returned to be the same. The values are equivalent under `equals` though, but their references (as tested by `eq`) are not.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your map is immutable but the keys you use for it are mutable or have incorrect `hashcode` and `equals` implementation that returns non deterministic results? What are the types you use?

Over-exaggerated example in REPL:

```
scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala> class BadKey(val value: Int) {
     |   override def hashCode = Random.nextInt(Int.MaxValue)
     | 
     |   override def equals(x: Any) = Random.nextBoolean
     | }
defined class BadKey

scala> val randMap = Map(new BadKey(1) -> 1, new BadKey(2) -> 2)
randMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[BadKey,Int] = Map(BadKey@26132448 -> 1,     BadKey@41e1cd27 -> 2)

scala> randMap.get(new BadKey(1))
res6: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> randMap.get(new BadKey(1))
res7: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> randMap.get(new BadKey(1))
res8: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> randMap.get(new BadKey(1))
res9: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> randMap.get(new BadKey(1))
res10: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> randMap.get(new BadKey(1))
res11: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: The keys are mutable (contain `var` fields) but they are not mutated between the two `apply` calls. The `hashcode` and `equals` methods are deterministic, they are implemented to depend only on one `val` field of the object and each object has a unique value for this field.